# Piping to gnuplot, doesn't accept multiple commands

Tags: c, stream, pipe, gnuplot, popen

I have the following code:

```
fprintf(temp->_fstream, "plot '-' using 1:2 title 'tittle1'\n");
```

`_fstream` is a gnuplot pipe, using the '-' enables to write the data to gnuplot directly instead of writing it first to a file, this is the code that does that:

```
 fprintf    (_stream->_fstream, "%d ", _node->count);
```

now I would like to plot another two columns say 1:3, for example in gnuplot you would do this using:

```
plot "output3.txt" using 1:2 title 'prey', "output3.txt" using 1:3 title 'predator'
```

but doing the same thing via a pipe it gives an error saying `unreachable data source` here is the line that I am using:

```
fprintf(temp->_fstream, "plot '-' using 1:2 title 'tittle1', '-' using 1:3 ... \n");
```

I've been looking at this for some time any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might need to create a pseudo-TTY to make gnuplot behave as if it's in interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`plot '-' us 1:2, '' us 1:2`

and enter (or write to the stream) the data followed by 'e'.
Then, enter the second set of data followed by 'e'.

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
e
1 2
2 3
3 4
e
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes I think i will have to re enter the data, the line above doesn't work, the only problem that the data is >10,000 so re entering it would be costly.